# is it possible to grab data from an .exe file in c++?

Tags: c++

I am new at C/C++,
So basically I want to call an .exe file that displays 2 numbers and be able to grab those two numbers to use them in my code.
To call the .exe file I've used the system command, but I am still not able to grab those two numbers that are displayed by the .exe file

```
char *files = "MyPath\file.exe";
system (files);
```

Comment: Look at redirecting Standard Output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is better aproach:
Here you just create new process, and you read data that process gives you. I tested this on OS X 10.11 with .sh file and works like a charm. I think that this would probably work on Windows also.

```
FILE *fp = popen("path to exe","r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Popen is null" << std::endl;
}else
{
    char buff[100];
    while ( fgets( buff, sizeof(buff), fp ) != NULL )
    {
        std::cout << buff;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks!! it worked perfectly, it does print the two numbers, but now how can i show only 1 of those two numbers??

Comment: which one? if you want first number just get rid of while loop and do just this in else statment:
`char buff[100]; fgets( buff, sizeof(buff), fp ); std::cout << buff;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escapr back slashes in `C++` string literals so:

```
// note the double "\\"
char* files = "MyPath\\file.exe";
```

Or just use forward slashes:

```
char* files = "MyPath/file.exe";
```

Its not very efficient but one thing you can to with `std::system` is redirect the output to a file and then read the file:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // redirect > the output to a file called output.txt
    if(std::system("MyPath\\file.exe > output.txt") != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: calling system\n";
        return 1; // error code
    }

    // open a file to the output data
    std::ifstream ifs("output.txt");

    if(!ifs.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: opening output file\n";
        return 1; // error code
    }

    int num1, num2;

    if(!(ifs >> num1 >> num2))
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: reading numbers\n";
        return 1; // error code
    }

    // do something with the numbers here
    std::cout << "num1: " << num1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "num2: " << num2 << '\n';
}
```

**NOTE:** (thnx @VermillionAzure)

> Note that system doesn't always work everywhere because unicorn
>   environments. Also, shells can differ from each other, like cmd.exe
>   and bash. –  VermillionAzure

When using `std::system` the results are platform dependant and not all shells will have redirection or use the same syntax or even exist!

Comment: Note that `system` doesn't always work everywhere because unicorn environments. Also, shells can differ from each other, like `cmd.exe` and `bash`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it compiles well but it does not prints anything on the console.

Comment: @user5231043 I added some error checking to the system call. Are you sure the path to the executable file is correct? Are there any error messages when you run it from the console?

Comment: @user5231043 I just added a comment pointing out you need to escape back slashes by doubling them. So your file name should be `MyPath\\file.exe`

Comment: there are not any error messages, it just opens an empty console; although I noticed that the "output.txt" was created successfully with the numbers on it, and actually I am using double slash.

Comment: @user5231043 If the file is being created then I have no idea why its not being opened. I added some more error checking to make sure the file opens. When you run that are you getting a message saying it didn't open?

Comment: it does not display anything, but i think it might have to do with the file path, but thanks anyways.